# Best practice for maintaining packages to be installed in chef

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I am trying to write cookbook for installing software in windows. when i use windows_package, installable is getting downloaded and installed. But post installation installable is not getting deleted. do we need to manually delete that file.

Is there any best practice to do this.

Comment: You should not remove a .msi file after install as it is used by windows hen uninstalling or if you need to repair the installation or change some features from the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally downloaded intermediary files are left in place because it makes the idempotence (don't redownload if you don't have to) checks easier. You could do fancier things where it only downloads if it isn't installed or if the version changes, but this is usually not worth the hassle.